# Sending a message to specific channel when user joins voice channel doesnt work

Tags: discord.js

Already looked for every issue on stackoverflow and nothing works.
I want my bot to send a message, if someone joins a **specific** voice channel.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // Here I'm storing the IDs of their voice channels, if available
  const oldChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel ? oldMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
  const newChannel = newMember.voiceChannel ? newMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
  if (oldChannel == newChannel) return; // If there has been no change, exit

  // Here I'm getting the client's channel (client.voiceChannel does not exist)
  const clientMember = oldMember.guild.member(client.user),
    clientChannel = clientMember ? clientMember.voiceChannel.id : null;

  // Here I'm getting the channel, just replace VVV this VVV with the channel's ID
  const textChannel = oldMember.guild.channels.get('765520462439645191');
  if (!textChannel) throw new Error("That channel does not exist.");

  // Here I don't need to check if they're the same, since it would've exit before
  if (newChannel == clientChannel) {
    // console.log("A user joined.");
    textChannel.send(`${newMember} has joined the voice channel.`);
  } else if (oldChannel == clientChannel) {
    // console.log("A user left.");
    textChannel.send(`${newMember} has left the voice channel.`);
  }
```

Doesnt work. No error but it doesnt work. Please help ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const newUserChannel = newMember.voice.channelID
  const oldUserChannel = oldMember.voice.channelID
  const textChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('TEXT CHANNEL ID')

  if(newUserChannel === 'VOICE CHANNEL ID') {
    textChannel.send(`${newMember.user.username} (${newMember.id}) has joined the channel`)
  } else if (oldUserChannel === 'VOICE CHANNEL ID' && newUserChannel !== 'VOICE CHANNEL ID') {
    textChannel.send(`${newMember.user.username} (${newMember.id}) has left the channel`)
  }
})
```

Comment: Although this might solve OP's problem, adding some explanation to why your code works and why OPs code doesn't will really boost the value of this answer.